# DocuSign RESTful API with formula/calculated fields

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating DocuSign envelopes using their RESTful API.
I need to include formula/calculated fields tab in my envelope. I am able to create the formula tab fine and perform calculations using the formula fine but when I want to place the formula tab based upon an anchor string, I am getting the following error.

```
 { "errorCode": "ANCHOR_TAB_STRING_NOT_FOUND", "message": "The specified Anchor Tab string was not found in the document. Anchor Tab String \"Requested Amount\" not found." }
```

I am able to insert the formula tab without anchor string fine.

Comment: can you please share the creation JSON request? and can you please confirm if you are able to add formula tab using DS Web App as well?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your underlying document may not be machine-readable by DocuSign. If you create an envelope through the Web Console using that same file, are you able to set up an Autoplace tag on the string "Requested Amount"?

Comment: I am able to place other tags using the same anchor so DocuSign is able to read my document fine.